# Database table (re)design. Combine multiple rows into one and assign primary key. Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, coda

I have a problem with the way I've designed my tables currently.

What I am doing is dealing with CODA files (its a Belgian banking standard). I am saving every transaction into the table and I am assigning a GUID key for every transaction.

Now, every single line is NOT a transaction, but rather a group of lines together constitute one transaction. I have addressed this by generating a key for every transaction and storing it into the 2 tables below. I have linked this via a third table where this key is the primary key.

My superior has asked me to get rid off this third table and rather combine every transaction into a single row in each of the 2 tables shown below (NOT the third table, since that would be deleted).

I am new to developing on SQL Server and visual studio. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Any ideas on this guys?

[image: bank statement summary]

[image: bank statement line]

[image: name_table]

Answer (score 0):

Just want to clarify before moving forward are you trying to concatenate such that (11 + 12 = (23 value when completed)) for a transaction or rather ((11, 12) value when completed) for a transaction?

Comment: I am trying to put all the data in the rows beginning with 21 and 31 into one single row. Similarly, the next set of data is from 21 to the next occurence of 21. So that all the data WITHIN (21 to 21) is in ONE SINGLE ROW. Same goes for the other table, all the data in rows BEGINNING with 0, 1, 8, 9 should be all in one single row.

Comment: I think I understand but there is a bit of an issue proceeding this way lets use the 21 row for example. lets say we append all the rows to a single row. so that the column labeled "amount" would hold the values (12500, 13000, 20000, 40000). This will turn the numbers into a string making calculations more challenging. Usually some kind of formatting like this would be done in the report builder, not directly in the database.

Comment: So best practice would be to either build this layout you are trying to achieve in a report builder such as SSRS, add the numbers together on another table (which will obscure some the data) but keep the original table and order it so information is grouped properly, or you could go with the string conversion route but as mentioned would make doing calculations more challenging. Let me know which you would prefer and then I will try to help.

Comment: So the thing is; the CODA files are essentially 130 chars long. Each line is 130 chars. They begin with 21, 31, 33, so on so forth. The beginning of each signifies what it is; (transaction record, movement record etc). What I've done now is to put each day's transaction into one single list (the day's tx begins with 0 and end ends with 9, as shown in the first table). I then proceed to save them to the database and assign a guid_key. I need to change this such that EACH transaction is in ONE row. ie. a set of 21, 31, 33.... and then another set of 21, 31, 32, 33... I can email you my code.

Comment: Yeah if you can send the code I can work on this. My email is robertlharrisiv@gmail.com.